# How to resolve Error java: package com.example.employee.response does not exist

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

My SpringBoot application has three modules

controller

service

dao

I am writing a test case for a class EmployeeDetailsController.java as  EmployeeDetailsControllerTest.java inside tests folder of a springboot application.

But when I run the EmployeeDetailsControllerTest I get the below error

```
java: package com.example.employee.response does not exist 
......
.......
```

This error is seen for all the imports used inside a java file EmployeeRegistrationController.java and import from other helper classes

I do not understand why it is pointing to the files in java package even when I run a test class inside tests package.

Below is the dependency I have added inside pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the structure. Sorry for the naming structure for the post and my project

[image]

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206997815-Unexpected-Package-Does-Not-Exist-Errors

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed by

```
Invalidate Caches/restart option of IntelliJ
```